# Information needed about a device to install OS on it?

Tags: android, architecture, operating-system, hardware

I am looking for the steps that one will have to go through when they have either old PDA or old smart phone and they want to install some sort of operating system.

For example: I have a Dell Axim X51v and I want to install android operating system on it.

So for that case, what information I should know before attempting this?
how can I know if some device X with an operating system Y can work fine together.

Or in general how can I tell if the architecture of some device X can handle some operating system Y.

Maybe this sound like trying to attach 2 pieces that usually do not go together.

I hope I make myself clear.

I will be happy to have title of books that kind of solve my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use Google and see if CyanogenMod or any other community projects have already created a port for that device.

Failing that, you can research your device's hardware to get the specifications like RAM, architecture etc. Depending on that, you can check which is the highest version of Android supported on that device. If a version of Android is supported, then you will have to write drivers for the hardware to be able to run Android on it, among other things.

Searching the history of the [Android Porting Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting) will give you people's attempts at such projects. You can also inquire on that list about the compatibility of a particular device.

Comment: Thanks man, I am sorry it took me that long.
I just wanted to know how can I do it myself so I needed some place to start other than depending on the work of other people like CyanogenMod.